# Is it necessary any configuration for yii2-httpclient works in production environment in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I am connecting a web with a API with https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient.

My call is the next:

```
$client = new Client();

$response = $client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->setUrl('http://'.Yii::$app->user->identity->building->ip.':40793/own_getproperties')
        ->setData(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id, 'min_date' => $min_date, 'max_date' => $max_date, 'language' => \Yii::$app->language])
        ->send();
```

In development environment (local), there is not problem, but when i upload to production environment, call does not occur.

Can you help me?

Comment: You should look for some errors in logs - this call should not be ignored without any warning.

Comment: Do you have `cUrl` installed on your live server ?